# Swift to Obj-c inside a pod

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode6

I'm developing a Pod(A) that uses another Pod(B). B pod has some code write in Swift, and my A pod is write in Objective-C. I tried a lot of approach from apple and other questions here, but I just can't import B pod inside my objc classes. Can anyone help?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

To use Swift project files in objective-c files you have to import the swift header. Add `#import "YourProject-Swift.h"` to your objective-c file. Also in your podfile make sure you add `use_frameworks!`

Comment: I tried to import like this ```#import "YourProject-Swift.h"```, trie to import the entire framework with ```@import YourProject```, and also with ```#import < YourProject/YourProject-Swift.h>```, but nothing worked

Comment: Since you are importing a pod try  `#import <PodB/PodB-Swift.h>` .